# Generate form with drop down using Gii in Yii

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii, generator, crud, gii

I am new to yii.I want to create model and form using Gii,In my database table i used enum data type for specific values to select by user.than i generate model and crude using Gii but it doesn't create drop-down list in form for that enum field.To create that drop-down using Gii what should i have to do. or change templates of Gii.
please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

change the `_form` and put your dropdown after creation by gii

```
echo $form->dropdownList($model , 'fieldName' , array(
   'private' => Yii::T('model' , 'private'), // give data as an array to populate your drop down
   'public' => Yii::T('model' , 'public'),
))
```

Comment: yii generates your _form.. You have to then edit it to meet your specific needs